# CSP: Trouble whitelisting url that changes, wildcard not working

Tags: content-security-policy

I've been having ongoing hurdles with my CSP policy and trying to whitelist the urls for my cookie banner (Iubenda). Between Chrome's developer tools and ReportURI, I can get everything to work and nothing gets blocked.

Until Iubenda updates it's vendor list (which happens randomly and often). They change the version # in the url so it no longer passes through my CSP. The most recent example: `https://cdn.iubenda.com/cs/tcf/v2/vendorlist.46.json` is whitelisted under "connect-src" and works. Except they just updated the vendorlist and the url is now `https://cdn.iubenda.com/cs/tcf/v2/vendorlist.47.json`

I tried using a wildcard to try an include future variations  of the file, or even to include all links that come from the site `httsp://cdn.iubenda.com/*` as well as including 'self' - but I have a feeling it's not the right solution. Is there a better way to write the exception so I don't have to keep checking every few weeks if they updated the link (which can prevent my cookie banner from displaying).
My coding skills are poor, so it could be something simple that I've missed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following here? https://www.iubenda.com/en/help/12260-how-to-configure-content-security-policy-to-allow-iubenda-scripts-to-execute
They suggest something similar:

```
Content-Security-Policy: 
  default-src 'self'; 
  script-src 'self' *.iubenda.com 'nonce-EDNnf03nceIOfn39fn3e9h3sdfa' 'unsafe-eval'; 
  connect-src *.iubenda.com; 
  style-src 'unsafe-inline' *.iubenda.com; 
  frame-src *.iubenda.com; 
  img-src *.iubenda.com data:
```